# How to use Redux to dispatch data to the backend (and consequently mongoDB)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-fullstack

I recently created a simple MERN application that is supposed to use a form to send data to the backend using Redux to maintain state management. I'm new to Redux (as you will see in my code) and I believe I must have messed up the dispatching.

Below are the functions in my Form component:

```
    const [landlordData, setLandlordData] = useState({name: '', type: '', rating: '', details: ''});
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(landlordData);
            dispatch(createLandlord(landlordData));
    }
```

Which console log the data from the form normally. When I submit though the new entry in the MongoDB only includes the time created and the UUID of the entry due to the Schema of the database:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const landlordSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    rating: Number,
    details: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
});

var landlordDetails = mongoose.model('Landlords', landlordSchema);

export default landlordDetails;
```

To provide more context on the backend operations here is the controller script I made:

```
import landlordDetails from '../models/landlords.js';

export const getLandlords = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const getDetails = await landlordDetails.find();   
        console.log(getDetails);

        res.status(200).json(getDetails);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

export const createLandlords = async (req, res) => {
    const details = req.body;

    const newLandlord = new landlordDetails(details);

    try {
        await newLandlord.save();

        res.status(201).json(newLandlord); 
        console.log("New landlord added!"); 
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed or if I am completely oblivious to something obvious. Thank you.

EDIT: To provide more context, here are my api calls and my action script:

API:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/landlords';

export const fetchLandlords = () => axios.get(url);
export const createLandlord = (landlordData) => axios.post(url, landlordData);
```

Actions JS file:

```
import * as api from '../api/index.js';

//Action creators

export const getLandlords = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchLandlords();

        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}; 

export const createLandlord = (landlord) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createLandlord(landlord);

        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE', payload: data });
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

When I click the submit button, a new database entry is made with the createdAt field but nothing else.

Comment: If im correct you're using redux thunk to pass the asynchronous function. can i see the function landlordDetails how are you making api call

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response!  landlordDetails is just the var name of the mongoose Schema I created for the MongoDB connection. Here is the file responsible for my API calls:

import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/landlords';

export const fetchLandlords = () => axios.get(url);
export const createLandlord = (landlordData) => axios.post(url, landlordData);

Comment: This is called from my actions script:

This is called from my actions script:


import * as api from '../api/index.js';

export const createLandlord = (landlord) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createLandlord(landlord);

        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE', payload: data });
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
};

Comment: @TarekElShennawy You need to edit your answer with these snippets, the code is not readable here in the comments.

Comment: I didn't know, it's been edited thank you!